# `git ls-remote` in GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

In my python program, I want to check whether a ref exists on my remote. I can check the remote with `git ls-remote`, but I would like to avoid parsing the output myself.

I found [`git.remote.Remote`](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#git.remote.Remote) in `GitPython`, but that only refers to a remote of a local repository.

Does `GitPython` have an equivalent command which allows me to look at remote refs without cloning the repository?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`GitPython` does not support `ls-remote`, but you can use `git.cmd` to run any git command and then parse the output manually:

```
import git
def lsremote(url):
    remote_refs = {}
    g = git.cmd.Git()
    for ref in g.ls_remote(url).split('\n'):
        hash_ref_list = ref.split('\t')
        remote_refs[hash_ref_list[1]] = hash_ref_list[0]
    return remote_refs
```

Example:

```
In [3]: refs = lsremote('https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython.git')
In [4]: refs['HEAD']
Out[4]: u'9f4af7c6db25c5bbec7fdc8dfc0ea6803350d94c'
```

Answer (score 2):

Case without cloning:

```
import git

url = "git://github.com/git/git.git"
g = git.cmd.Git()
g.ls_remote("--tags", url).split('\n')
```

I left a parsing of output for you, but I have some example

```
>>> test = g.ls_remote("--tags", url).split('\n')
>>> print(test[0])
d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as well.

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo('path to source')
repo.git.ls_remote("--heads", "origin", "release/10.0.0.2")
```

Output will be something like:

> '9e5ca005c2d320a4904e88e25df1efa6fb26b396\trefs/heads/release/10.0.0.2'